# RuntimeException Unable to start activity: Permission Denial: broadcast from android asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0

Tags: java, android

Faced with the error from Google report (Android 9):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
broadcast from android asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this 
requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or 
android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
```

Can't reproduce and can't find any clue.

What can cause this? Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: please share your logcat

Comment: I don't have, it's crashlytics issue (same as in my post, no other traces), I can't reproduce it and can't get same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this android:protectionLevel="signature" in your manifest .

For more details, you can check [Permission-Element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)

Like:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```